# How do I store my results which are of the form of graphs and numerical outputs/ Is there a universal way of storing any kind of result in python?

Tags: python, storage, storing-data, storing-information

I am writing a program that runs for a long time. I want to run this program many times so that I can see the dependence of my results on the tweaking of parameters.
So, suppose a situation similar to the following:

```
parameter=1

"Big code that takes a long time"


print(output, "output that depends on t")
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Now change the parameter to 2 and re-run again. I want to be able to pull the results of the previous one so that I can compare them.

So I want to sort of store them somehow so that the next time I need to look at the results I just have to execute a few lines and the stored results come up really quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all the information such as the inputs, params, and outputs in a dictionary. You can then use the dict to do further plotting and analysis.

Here I add a minimal reproducible example. You can use this as a reference for your needs. The below code produces this plot as an output.[image: input_vs_output_various_params]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

def big_code(param, input):
    output = [i + param**(random.randrange(2, 5)) for i in input]
    return output

def plot_experiments(info):
    rows, cols = 1, 6
    _, axs = plt.subplots(rows,cols)
    i = 0

    for val in info.values():
        param_idx = val['param']
        axs[i].plot(val['input'], val['output'])
        axs[i].set_title(f'param {param_idx}')       
        i+=1

    for ax in axs.flat:
        ax.set(xlabel='x-label', ylabel='y-label')

    # Hide x labels and tick labels for top plots and y ticks for right plots.
    for ax in axs.flat:
        ax.label_outer()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_params = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    input_list = np.array(list(range(2000)))
    info = {}
    
    for exp_id ,param in enumerate(input_params):
        # Run your big code to get output
        output = big_code(param, input_list)

        # Save your output to a dataframe
        info[exp_id] = {'input': input_list, 'output': output, 'param': param }
        
    # Access your dict and plot
    plot_experiments(info)
```